# asp:XmlDataSource Expected DTD markup was not found. Line 1, position 3

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html

I Trying to read this Rss.

http://www.alhadath.net/.mrss/alhadath.xml

or this.

http://www.alarabiya.net/.mrss/ar/arab-and-world.xml

it's look like this

```
 <rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
```

and both of them return back with this error

***Expected DTD markup was not found. Line 1, position 3.***

this this my simile code

```html
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmlRSS"
                DataFile="http://www.alarabiya.net/.mrss/ar/arab-and-world.xml"
                EnableCaching="true"
                CacheDuration="3600"
                XPath="rss/channel/item"
                runat="server" />
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptRSS" runat="server" DataSourceID="xmlRSS">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <p>
                    <a href='<%#XPath("link")%>' target="_blank"><%#XPath("title")%></a>
                </p>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

this way working fine with other RSS like

http://arabic.cnn.com/World/rss

or

http://ekhbaryamubsher.com/?feed=rss2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work fine 
the problem is from RSS urls

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmlRSS"
                DataFile="http://www.alarabiya.net/.mrss/ar/arab-and-world.xml"
                EnableCaching="true"
                CacheDuration="3600"
                XPath="rss/channel/item"
                runat="server" />
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptRSS" runat="server" DataSourceID="xmlRSS">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <p>
                    <a href='<%#XPath("link")%>' target="_blank"><%#XPath("title")%></a>
                </p>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```